# Below code return null after converting secret key to bytearray

Tags: android, security, encryption, cryptography, secret-key

I have generated a secret key and I want to convert it to string. Below code is generating secret key to byte array but bytearray returning null

```java
String alias = email + "Secret";
final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM).setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE).build();

keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
System.out.println(secretKey);

byte[] data = secretKey.getEncoded();
System.out.println("byteArray:" + data);
```

Comment: That's the point of the AndroidKeyStore, you can't get sensitive key material out of it. It is supposed to return null in this case. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore): "Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable. "

Comment: I got that. Thank you very much james